# SQL Server - Query logs?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, sql-server-2008

any idea where I can read logs of recent queries?

Errors are coming back when using Django for queries that seem to be alright, and cannot understand what is wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example of the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understanded you need [MS SQL Profiler](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms181091.aspx&rct=j&q=sql%20profiler&ei=7Pb4TLCfD8Gv4Aay7732Bw&usg=AFQjCNHqAcM2nSfDP81KaUhYDgeRk6pfDA&sig2=ORVtusbLtGGkoNTvBuI6Og&cad=rja).  But it log only new queries.

Answer (score 3):

There are no logs of recent queries. You can use SQL Profiler / SQL Trace to monitor queries ongoing though.

You can also look in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` for recent plans and associated text which might help depending on whether the error was a parse/compilation error or not.

```
select text from
sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 and above, you can track the DDL queries using the [Default Trace](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2005/64547/).